# Проверить, являются ли все цифры данного натурального числа различными (СИ)

Tags: c, арифметика

При вводе числа 101 или ему подобного программа выдает положительный результат, хотя должно быть наоборот

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int power(int n, int i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return power(n, (i - 1)) * n;
    }
    int Check (int n) {
        int i = 1, k = (n / power(10, i)) % 10;
            if (n >= 1 && n < 10)
                return 1;
            else
                while (k != 0) {
                    if ((n % 10) == k) {
                        return 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        i++;
                        k = (n / power(10, i)) % 10;
                    }
                }
    }
    int main () {
        long long n; 
        int i, j = 0, k;
        scanf ("%lld", &n);
            for (i = n; i >= 0; i /= 10)
                    if (Check(i) == 1) {
                        puts ("True");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Check(i) == 2) {
                        puts ("False");
                        break;
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другая версия функции, которой не обязательно по всему числу идти :)

```
int checkDIfferent(int n) {
bool digs[10] = { 0 };
while (n > 0) {
    if (digs[n % 10])
        return 0;
    digs[n % 10] = true;
    n /= 10;
}
return 1;
}
```

Специально для Harry:

```
int checkDIfferent(int n) {
    bool digs[10] = { 0 };
    for (; n && !digs[n % 10]; n /= 10) digs[n % 10] = true;
    return n == 0 || !digs[n % 10];
}
```

А можно и так. Почему нет?:

```
int checkDIfferent1(int n) {
unsigned short int digs = 0;
while (n > 0) {
    if (digs & (1 << (n % 10)))
        return 0;
    digs |= (1 << (n % 10));
    n /= 10;
}
return 1;
}
```

Продолжение следует?...

Comment: Да, логичная оптимизация. Но мой вариант можно еще дооптимизировать - см. у меня в ответе :)

Answer (score 2):

"Зачем просто, если можно сложно?!" (с)

```
int checkDifferent(int n)
{
    int digs[10] = {0};
    for(;n;n/= 10) digs[n%10]++;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) if (digs[i]>1) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Или даже

```
int check(int n)
{
    for(int digs[10] = {0};n && ++digs[n%10] <= 1;n/=10);
    return n == 0;
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, мне как то `bool` больше нравится :)

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Да, но метка-то `c`, не `c++`...

Comment: Хмм хорошо, мне тогда больше нравится `unsigned short int`

Comment: `unsigned char` уже не получится, ну и ладно. Но все же массив, как-то не красиво выглядит :)