# C++ :напечатать все слова, отличающиеся от последнего слова, и не содержщие повтряющихся букв

Tags: c++

С++ :Слова текста из малых латиских букв записаны не менее чем через один пробел;текст окончивается
точкой. БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ конструкции STRING и функций из этого пакета:
a) написать программу ввода такого текста с клавиатуры
б)напечатать все слова, отличающиеся от последнего слова, и не содержщие повтряющихся букв
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Выложите свои попытки решить эту задачу, и если возникнет конкретная проблема, то мы поможем.

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задач

Answer (score 0):

Ладно помогу вам, надеюсь ответ вам понравится.

По порядку, что вам нужно написать:

1. **Ввести строку с пробелами.**

   Вот тут отлично все расписано: [ссылка](https://proginfo.ru/getline/)
2. **Разбить строку на массив слов**

   Если писать самому алгоритм, то можно и без массива слов обойтись, но вряд ли, задавая такой вопрос вы сможете написать сами такой алгоритм.

   Вот пример разбиение строки на слова при помощи функции `strtok`: [ссылка](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

   Если вы не можете использовать эту функцию, то учите [циклы](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/2.13.php) и [символьные массивы](https://purecodecpp.com/archives/845) (строка СИ)
3. После вы пишите две функции, первая эта функция сравнения слов, которая возвращает например `true` если строки равны. Вот [пример](http://www.prostocpp.narod.ru/compare_of_strings.html). А вторая функция возвращает `true` если в слове есть повторяющиеся слова. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221396/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%A1%D0%98/1221422#1221422), конечно там проверяется на повторение цифр, но идея та же. (Если что пользуйтесь гуглом и найдете)

Ну а дальше слова, которые подходят вы выводите, остальные пропускаете :)